# Liferay 6.2 - how to use Asset Publisher in JSP?

Tags: liferay, portlet, sitemap, portal, liferay-6.2

I want to add an asset publisher in my Portlet and i want to configure the asset and any other portlets to be already configured to be able to deploy (drag and drop) anytime and anywhere in my site so would you please help me to find a solution for my problem

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related according to your comment in Chris' answer. Watch out for "Archive/Restore Setup" in 6.2 or "Configuration Template" in Liferay 7 in a portlet's menu.

Comment: so, thanks for your answer but i want to be sure that according to your answer your mean there is no programming answer for this situation ??

Comment: whoops, now that I'm re-reading your comment: I first read that you are *not* looking for a separate plugin and that was obviously my mistake. However, the vote to close stays up, just the reason changes. Stackoverflow helps you to debug your code, if you post minimal snippets. "How do I write X?", e.g. looking for tutorials or sample code is out of scope here. However, what you're asking for can be done without programming. Of course you can develop something like AssetPublisher yourself as well. You've just selected one of the most complex built-in portlets for this.

Comment: thanks for your answer and i would like to ask you how\where i can contact you if i have any question in the near future ???

Answer (score 1):

## Asset Publisher

The asset publisher can be configured to use inside your custom plugin portlet project using the associated taglibs and SDK.  For the Asset functionality the following programmatic definitions will be used.

#### Taglibs

- asset-categories-error
- asset-categories-navigation
- asset-categories-selector
- asset-categories-summary
- asset-links
- asset-tags-error
- asset-tags-navigation
- asset-tags-selector
- asset-tags-summary

[Taglibs](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/taglibs/liferay-ui/tld-summary.html)

#### Packages

- com.liferay.portlet.asset
- com.liferay.portlet.asset.model
- com.liferay.portlet.asset.service
- com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.persistence
- com.liferay.portlet.asset.util.comparator
- com.liferay.portlet.assetpublisher.util

[JavaDocs](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/)

#### Conclusion

The above information will give you a good place to begin using the Asset functionality in your custom plugin project.  I realize this does not give you a concrete explanation of the functionality but in order to do that you need a specific question.  The Asset functionality is too broad of a topic to describe in a post.  Please reference the above material and ask a more pointed question

Comment: you didn't get my point 

i wanted to make a new plugin portlet like the asset publisher but with configurations that i want and when i deploy (drag and drop) the new asset publisher i wanted it to be configured with the configuration that i already configure.